# clustermarkers in leaflet providing density information in R

Tags: r, leaflet, gis

I am wondering if it is possible for clusterMarkers in leaflet to display frequency information instead of the number of markers clustered?

I have the following code

```
getColor <- function(my.df) {
  sapply(my.df$value, function(value) {
  if(value <= 5) {
    "green"
  } else if(value <= 25) {
    "orange"
  } else {
    "red"
  } })
}
icons <- awesomeIcons(
  icon = 'ios-close',
  iconColor = 'black',
  library = 'ion',
  markerColor = getColor(my.df)
)


map <- my.df %>% 
    leaflet () %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addAwesomeMarkers(icon=icons, label=~as.character(freq), clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
map
```

my.df is in the following format

```
longitude latitude freq
XX.xxx    XX.xxx    3
XX.xxx    XX.xxx    7
XX.xxx    XX.xxx    4
.
.
.
XX.xxx    XX.xxx    6
```

What I would like is for the cluster to display the aggregate of the value for my.df$freq rather than the number of pins in the cluster. I am not sure how to do this though or if there is even a clusterOption for this.

Comment: please report `dput(my.df)`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible.

You have to make use of *iconCreateFunction* function which is inserted as an option to MarkerClusterGroup for creating custom cluster icons. You also need to make use of *getAllChildMarkers()* function to iterate through all children of a cluster and calculate aggregate value.

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        let children = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();

        let sum = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            sum += children[i].options.value;
        }

        return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<b>' + sum + '</b>' });
    }
}).addTo(map);

L.circleMarker([0,0], {value: 10}).addTo(markers);
L.circleMarker([10,0], {value: 20}).addTo(markers);
L.circleMarker([40,10], {value: 60}).addTo(markers);
```

Of course, you can customize the icon.

This jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/41mknp5s/1/ is an implementation of the above code. Zoom in/out to see the cluster showing the sum values of the markers.

Comment: I am unable to implement this correctly in R. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know R but I would suggest you share your code with us.

Comment: This is a JavaScript solution, not R.

Comment: As I mentioned, I dont know R but I wrote the logic in Javascript, for a plugin that is written in Javascript. You could transform it to R code.